# How to do Maximum Covariance Analysis in R?

Tags: r, covariance

Maximum covariance analysis (MCA) has been used to detect coupled modes of the variability between two time series. MCA constructs a covariance matrix between two datasets and then performs a singular value decomposition (SVD) of the resulting matrix.

I want to do a Maximum Covariance Analysis for two time series in R and I have searched many R packages, but find no results. Is there any way to do this in R? Thanks a lot.

The final goal is to find the MCA for two time series and plot the MCA coefficients.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled on the same problem a few months ago. I believe there isn't any exhaustive R package to perform a MCA, of course I may be wrong.

However I did get precious help from the following [post](http://menugget.blogspot.fr/2011/11/empirical-orthogonal-function-eof.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help.